# SVN checkout fails saying URL is malformed

Tags: linux, svn, redhat, vcs-checkout

I am trying to checkout files using subversion on RedHat Linux but the checkout fails saying URL (http/https) is malformed or the scheme or host or path is missing.

I am not sure now what more configuration/setup is needed?

I am able to ping the http(s) site properly.

Command:

```
svn checkout --username kdeshpa https://teamforge.wal-mart.com/svn/repos/demo
```

If I run `svn log`, it cribs saying (svn: '.' is not a working copy).

Comment: Could you give an example of the URL?

Comment: The whole command line would be even better.

Comment: If you have access to the SVN server, check the apache access_log and error_log ... see how the URLs are getting passed in. Report what the logs say here.

Comment: Check your proxy or firewall isn't blocking it. You may be having authentication issues.

Comment: For fun, try connecting to site using TortoiseSVN.

Comment: The command line looks fine, can you copy'n'paste the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that SSL handshake issue. Had to build openssl with "no-asm" configuration and it was able to checkout on secured layer.

Comment: That's freaky!  Did you report a bug to RedHat?

Answer (score 0):

(Oddly, I am not allowed to comment on this issue, so instead I will answer.)

Have you tried to install the neon package?
You can find the source here: http://www.webdav.org/neon/

When I compiled an SVN client from scratch recently, I was unable to connect to an SVN repo using HTTP.  After installing neon, I recompiled and my SVN client was able to connect to an SVN repo using HTTP.

Comment: Check the FAQ on the reputation requirements for commenting. As your reputation increases, more functionality is provided to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have neon installed, and compiled with SSL support. On Solaris I pass the following flags to Neon's configure script: `--enable-threadsafe-ssl=posix --with-ssl=openssl`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with SVN repo using simple HTTP and the solution was also simple. I had to modify the PATH environment value. My /opt/subversion/bin was the last entry in the PATH so I have moved it into the front. The problem solved.

I have got the idea from here: http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2010-06/0094.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$which svn
```

See the path from which svn is being used currently. Now try,

```
$where svn
```

And see if at all other versions of svn are present in your local system. Try pointing the svn you are using to a different one by editing the $PATH.

I actually used a different version of svn and that worked for me.